# Executar função JavaScript ao recarregar a página

Tags: javascript, rolamento

Tenho 2 botões que coloquei no menu, e quando rola o *scroll* aparece 1 e some o outro porque o menu muda de cor (estou mandando as imagens para melhor visualização).

Até aí tudo bem. Está fazendo do jeito que quero. Porém, ao recarregar a página, mostra os dois botões e a função de revelar e esconder só funcionar quando rola o *scroll*. Eu queria executa-la logo quando recarregar a página e o botão preto só aparecesse ao rolar a página.

Meu código:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

    if($(document).scrollTop() > 50 ){// se a rolagem passar de 200px esconde o elemento

        $('.maxbutton-6.maxbutton.maxbutton-botao3.fancybox.iframe').fadeIn(0); // Esconde usando fadeOut

    } else { // senão ele volta a ser visivel

        $('.maxbutton-6.maxbutton.maxbutton-botao3.fancybox.iframe').fadeOut(0); // Mostra usando fadeIn

    }

});

$(window).scroll(function(){
         if($(document).scrollTop() > 50){// se a rolagem passar de 200px esconde o elemento

        $('.maxbutton-5.maxbutton.maxbutton-area3.fancybox.iframe').fadeOut(0); // Esconde usando fadeOut

    } else { // senão ele volta a ser visivel

        $('.maxbutton-5.maxbutton.maxbutton-area3.fancybox.iframe').fadeIn(); // Mostra usando fadeIn

    }


});
```

Comment: Leitura recomendada (sobre a comunidade): [formatação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 3):

É só chamar um `.trigger("scroll")` no mesmo objeto `window` que cria o evento scroll:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

   if($(document).scrollTop() > 50 ){// se a rolagem passar de 200px esconde o elemento

      $('.maxbutton-6.maxbutton.maxbutton-botao3.fancybox.iframe').fadeIn(0); // Esconde usando fadeOut
      $('.maxbutton-5.maxbutton.maxbutton-area3.fancybox.iframe').fadeOut(0);

   } else { // senão ele volta a ser visivel

      $('.maxbutton-6.maxbutton.maxbutton-botao3.fancybox.iframe').fadeOut(0); // Mostra usando fadeIn
      $('.maxbutton-5.maxbutton.maxbutton-area3.fancybox.iframe').fadeIn();

   }

}).trigger("scroll"); // AQUI DISPARA O EVENTO SCROLL
```

Agora, você não precisa (nem deveria) repetir o event handler para cada coisa, basta colocar tudo num só.

> Outra coisa é colocar o valor `0` nos fades. Isso não faz sentido
>   porque irá anular o efeito. Seria como usar `.show()` e `.hide()`. Se
>   deseja aquele efeito de esmaecimento, retire o valor ou coloque um
>   valor diferente de `0` (o valor padrão é `400`).

**Exemplo de funcionamento:**

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){

   if($(document).scrollTop() > 50 ){// se a rolagem passar de 200px esconde o elemento
   
      $('.maxbutton-6.maxbutton.maxbutton-botao3.fancybox.iframe').fadeIn(); // Esconde usando fadeOut
      $('.maxbutton-5.maxbutton.maxbutton-area3.fancybox.iframe').fadeOut();

   } else { // senão ele volta a ser visivel
   
      $('.maxbutton-6.maxbutton.maxbutton-botao3.fancybox.iframe').fadeOut(); // Mostra usando fadeIn
      $('.maxbutton-5.maxbutton.maxbutton-area3.fancybox.iframe').fadeIn();
   
   }

}).trigger("scroll");
```

```css
body, html{
   height: 1500px;
}

div{
   position: fixed;
   top: 10px;
   left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
   <button class="maxbutton-6 maxbutton maxbutton-botao3 fancybox iframe">Botão > 50px</button>
   <button class="maxbutton-5 maxbutton maxbutton-area3 fancybox iframe">Botão < 50px</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Não está dando certo, amigo ! coloquei o trigger no final mas continuou doo mesmo jeito. a função só está executando quando abaixa o scroll, mas na hora em que carrega aparece os dois botoes.

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada....

Comment: no seu exemplo deu certo, porém no meu está dando algo de errado.

Comment: Faz assim: retire o `.trigger("scroll");`.... adicione o código: `$(document).ready(function(){ $(window).trigger("scroll"); });`

Comment: Amigo eu conseguir fazer isso de outra forma. 
eu deixei o botao preto em opaco nas configurações css.
e mandei um codigo para aparecer só ao rolar o scroll e funcionaou do jeito que eu queria, agora ao carregar a pagina ele executa o css e ao rolar o scrooll ele execulta o java. eu agradeço pela atenção que  deu ao meu problema, obrigado !

Answer (score 0):

[image: ao carregar a pagina]

[image: ao rolar scrool]

[image: ao voltar scrool]

eu queria que ao carregar a pagina o botao preto já ficasse opaco e só aparecesse ao rolar o scrool, mas ao carregar a pagina ele já aparece e fica mostrando os dois botoes